# Translating a scientific paper from American to British

Tags: american-english, british-english, science

Over the last few years I have translated into English a fair amount of scientific papers for a Mexican scientist. Throughout this time, I noticed that by far the most common style requirement was asking the paper to be written in either American or British English. I have no problem with American since in Mexico we usually learn the American dialect, but writing a paper in British is a whole different story.

Throughout this time, I've looked up online as many guides on how to migrate a document from American to British English, but the most I've been able to find was [this short guide on American vs. British spelling](https://www.aje.com/en/arc/editing-tip-american-and-british-english/) as well as a few vocabulary guides (e.g. "French fries", "truck" and "drugstore" vs. "chips", "lorry" and "chemist"). Entering queries on Google like "how to translate from American to British English" yields almost no meaningful results.

If anyone has some pointers on how to translate a scientific paper from American to British English, I would be extremely thankful.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a reminder, Stack Exchange questions should be posed to seek a single authoritative answer; requests for open-ended lists of suggestions, tips, recommendations, pointers, and so on are very ill-suited to the format. *Translation* is probably not the term you want, and may explain your difficulty finding resources. Just search on *differences* between British and American English and you will find scads of articles, websites, papers, and other guides.

Comment: I've already googled them before, but the sheer bulk of these differences make it way too cumbersome to migrate a document from American to British using one of these guides. This is a problem, because scientific papers are subject to deadlines, so a simple and concise guide is necessary. Preferrably, a guide saying "change -or to -our except for these words, change these American words to these British words".

Comment: The goal is to have paper reviewers read the document and declare it conforms to their style specifications.

Comment: Things are just not that simple. Not every *program* becomes a *programme*.  Some *fillet* is *fillet* but some is *filet*. An American ton is lighter than an Imperial ton. But the point remains that open-ended requests for help are not good Stack Exchange questions, and further that requests for resources, if you are asking for a particular guide or manual, are not on-topic here (although you can post them on the [Meta site](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/)).

Comment: Add also the BrE spelling for *defence*, *aluminium*, *centre*, *sulphur* (to name just a few), and the *marvellous* [rule for double L](https://howtospell.co.uk/double-l-spelling-rule). I think the only solution is to become transatlantically bilingual :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is about writing resources so I'm flagging it as off-topic here - see our guidance on [ask]. However, with some minor rewriting it would be suitable on our other site [writing.se] - see their [on-topic page](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for what's suitable. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your spellchecker in MSWord to 'English (United Kingdom)' and it will catch all but the words that can be spelled correctly either way in English - there are a few 'ise' / 'ize' ending words like that. There really aren't that many words that are different if you're translating a scientific paper.

Comment: Does Google Drive also have that option? My lifestyle requires that I use cloud tools to translate papers so I hardly use MS Word for that.

Comment: @RAKK Try this: File > Language > English (United Kingdom).

Answer (score 3):

Most of the differences in technical writing are spellings. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences) has an article with plenty of examples. Common ones are endings: *-re* instead of *-er*, *-our* instead of *-or* and *-ise* instead of *-ize* (though the latter is accepted by some authorities in British English. There are plenty of others. Whole words include *sulphur* and *aluminium* in some contexts - in others the spellings chosen by IUPAC (chemistry) are used whatever flavour of English is used. *-ae-* and *-oe-* are much more common in British English, a simple *-e-* is used in American (many words in a medical context, for example)

The other differences tend to be:

- more idiomatic and therefore less suitable for technical writing than alternative phrasing.
- widely understood, to the point that whether they're Americanisms or not is a matter for debate.
- variable between style guides anyway.

A few specific cases are worth mentioning (addressed from the point of view of academic British English):

- *gotten* isn't a word.
- *spelt* is the past tense of *spell* and not just a form of wheat (*spelled* is also acceptable).
- British English is more likely to double a final consonant when adding a suffix.
- we fly in aeroplanes not airplanes.